# Chef IIS cookbook - how do you point an application at a new directory?

Tags: iis-7, chef-recipe, appcmd

I'm trying to repoint an IIS application at a different directory on disk.

The `iis_app` chef resource does not appear to support such an action.  I know how to do it in Powershell but the IIS cookbook leverages appcmd. So I've reverted to `appcmd` and still can't get the command to work:

```
appcmd set app /app.name: contoso / marketing /[path='/'].physicalPath:c:\ application
```

Comment: Are you having problems with the `appcmd` itself or just running it via the chef recipe?  What errors are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matt for your interest - i have solve this issue as follows:
In essence i was asking 2 questions:

1. How do you use appcmd to point an application at another place on
   disk.
2. How do i use the Chef iis cookbook resources to do likewise

Answers

1. The correct appcmd is

>
appcmd.exe set vdir "contoso/marketing/" -physicalPath:c:\application

2. It turned out that there was a bug in the iis cookbook when i used this resource to do the same as the appcmd above

`is_vdir "contoso/" do
 path 'marketing/'
 physical_path "c:\application"
 action :config
 end`

This bug was fixed in in the iis community cookbook(iis 3.0.12) : [https://github.com/EasyAsABC123/iis/tree/hotfix-issue_with_helper](http://iis) and works as intended.